# Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object PNPDeviceID, MediaType ===> what will be MediaType for External Hard Drives?

Tags: windows, powershell, hard-drive

when i connect External Hard Drive and type in powershell as administrator:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object PNPDeviceID, MediaType
```

i get MediaType as "`External hard disk media`" for external one and "`Fixed hard disk media`" for internal hard disk.

My question is: Is this MediaType for external Hard Drives is consistent, can i use this to filter externals or will it change at some place? And should i consider translation of it to different languages if system lang is not english?

This is all, Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: According to the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive, possible values also include “Removable media other than floppy” and “Format is unknown”…

Comment: Historically some USB drives have reported themselves as being fixed media. Not sure if that's still the case but it's not 100% reliable.

Comment: My next question would be: "Whatfor do you need it?". 

Comment: You should consider using `Get-CimInstance`. The `Wmi` commands are not available in PowerShell Core.